# "invalid version specification" error occured when reactlog started

Tags: r, shiny

When I tried to draw a reactive graph according to [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html#the-reactlog-package) I pressed cmd+F3 to start reactlog, but I got the follow
error.

[image: JBEHUKl.png]

The R I'm using was installed by mamba and it seems I have all dependencies installed. How can I fix this ?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/user/bin/mambaforge/envs/py310/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] fontawesome_0.5.0 htmltools_0.5.4   rmarkdown_2.20    knitr_1.42        testthat_3.1.6    reactlog_1.1.1    shiny_1.7.4       magrittr_2.0.3    lubridate_1.9.2  
[10] forcats_1.0.0     dplyr_1.1.0       purrr_1.0.1       readr_2.1.4       tidyr_1.3.0       tibble_3.1.8      tidyverse_2.0.0   ggplot2_3.4.1     stringr_1.5.0    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0 xfun_0.37        bslib_0.4.2      colorspace_2.1-0 vctrs_0.5.2      generics_0.1.3   utf8_1.2.3       rlang_1.0.6      pillar_1.8.1    
[10] jquerylib_0.1.4  later_1.3.0      glue_1.6.2       withr_2.5.0      bit64_4.0.5      lifecycle_1.0.3  munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.1     memoise_2.0.1   
[19] evaluate_0.20    tzdb_0.3.0       fastmap_1.1.1    httpuv_1.6.9     fansi_1.0.4      Rcpp_1.0.10      xtable_1.8-4     scales_1.2.1     promises_1.2.0.1
[28] cachem_1.0.7     vroom_1.6.1      jsonlite_1.8.4   mime_0.12        bit_4.0.5        brio_1.1.3       hms_1.1.2        digest_0.6.31    stringi_1.7.12  
[37] grid_4.2.2       cli_3.6.0        tools_4.2.2      sass_0.4.5       crayon_1.5.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3  ellipsis_0.3.2   timechange_0.2.0 rstudioapi_0.14 
[46] R6_2.5.1         compiler_4.2.2
```

By the way Google can't give your a proper solution